# Spyder has encountered an internal problem

Tags: python, error-handling, spyder

I run the code here, but it came out the error ' Spyder has encountered an internal problem' ,

it can be run in IDLE environment but not in Spyder.
There are less imformation about this on the internet,

Can anybody help me?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def read_data(ticker): 
    try:
        data = pd.read_csv(f'stock\{ticker}.csv')
        print(ticker,'\n')
        print('data : ', data.head())
        return data
    except:
        pass


ticker_symbol = eval(input("ticker sympol : "))
data  = read_data(ticker_symbol)


x = np.array(data['日期'][ :100 ])
y = data['成交筆數'][ : 100]
for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i] = int(y[i].replace
```

Comment: It is probably the 成交筆數 characters breaking with the encoding. Recheck the encoding.